# Title is undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Currently I have a web page that users can title and create new "games" . What should happen is a user enters the name into a text box, hits "create" then the game is created.

Currently when the user hits create , the GUID is generated an the game is created. If the user named the  game Test, it should display, Game: Test Remove( clicking remove removes the game.) However the game is listed as , Game: undefined Remove.

I've been able to identify the problem, the problem is that title is undefined. How should i go about defining the title thank you.

Here is my code

Controller

```
using PlanningPoker.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace PlanningPoker.Controllers {
public class GMController : ApiController {
    private static List<Game> games = new List<Game>() {
            new Game() {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Title = "D&D"
            }
        };

    [Route("data/games")]
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetAllGames() {
        return games;
    }

    [Route("data/games/create"), HttpPost]
    public Guid CreateGame(string title) {
        Game g = new Game() {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Title = title
        };

        games.Add(g);

        return g.ID;
    }


    [Route("data/games/remove"), HttpPost]
    public void RemoveGame(Guid id) {
        games.RemoveAll(g => g.ID == id);
    }
 }
}
```

Index (hmtl) (users can create games here, created games are displayed here)

```
<head>
<title>Planning Poker</title>
<style>
    .inlinetext {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/GameSVC.js"></script>
<script src="Gamelist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#button').on('click', function (data) {
            svc.Game.Add($('#testtxt').val(), function (d) { console.log(d), window.location.reload(); });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>



<body>
<h3 class='inlinetext'> Create Game: </h3>
    <input type="text" id="testtext" name="ime">
    <button id="button" >Create</button>

<h4>Games</h4>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data:$data.games, as:'$game' }">
    <li>
        Game :
        <span data-bind="text: $game.Title"> </span>
        <a data-bind="click: function(d,e) { $parent.removeGame(d); }">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>


</body>

 </html>
```

Gamelist (js)

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.games = ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON("/data/games", function (d) {
    self.games(d);
});


self.removeGame = function (game) {

    svc.Game.Remove(game.ID, function () {
       $.getJSON("/data/games", function (d) {
            self.games(d);
        });
    });
}

}
$(function () {
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

Game SVC

```
var svc = svc || {
Game: {
    Add: function (title, cb) {
        $.post('data/games/create/?title='+title, cb);
    },
    Remove: function (id, cb) {
        $.post("data/games/remove/?id=" + encodeURIComponent(id), cb);
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Your mixing knockout and jquery in a way that is not ideal. So there is a lot that would need to change to get things working. Have you looked at these examples (http://knockoutjs.com/examples/)? Notice that in the Better list example, the add button is bound to a function and there is no use of jquery's on or onclick in the code.

Comment: The result (named `d` here) of a `$.getJSON` is not an array, it is a plain object